# Foreach File Enumerator is missing from list of Enumerators in For Each Loop Container

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I am learning SSIS and while working with For Each Loop Container, I found that from the list of available Enumerators, the "ForEach File" Enumerator is not present.

I am working with SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition (one instance) and Enterprise Eval Edition (for another instance).

Why is that the For Each Loop Container Enum is absent from the list of available Enums?

**:Update:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Siva: I have already visited this link. That wasn't useful.

Comment: Yes @Siva: I see the .dll in the mentioned path!

Comment: Can you post an image with what you are seeing on the toolbox of your control flow?

Comment: @Lamak: I have updated the question with the image as asked.

Comment: @SmithPascalJr. Sorry, I didn't read correctly your question. Is it possible for you to upload an image of the dropdown list of the enumerators?

Comment: @Lamak: Image of Enum ddls is uploaded as requested.

Comment: Any comments??? Please assist

Comment: Run SQL Server setup and choose Maintenance->Repair.

Comment: @Aryadev:I have alreday done "Repair"